# Blueprism get all files contained in a root folder

Tags: blueprism

I have a root folder with multiple sub folders and those sub folders could have more sub folders and so on and so forth. I want to run an action and pass it the base folder and get all files that are contained in there (Even in sub folders). The Get files action only gets the files at the first level and to use get folders you'd need to create a huge process which checks every level to see if there are more sub folders and you could potentially miss some files.

Comment: "*and you could potentially miss some files*" If you're using recursion as you describe, how do you figure some files would simply be arbitrarily excluded? There is no way to do this out of the box, but performing these operations recursively should meet your requirements as you've described them here.

Comment: So I mean you would use get folders and check are there any sub folders and basically you'd have to define how many times to do it. If you built this check 10 times there could be a sub folder 11 levels deep. Is there an intelligent loop structure that can be done to basically keep digging till it's found everything?

Comment: look into using a while loop and set the condition to repeat if the folder you have just entered has any subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

run the command through command prompt maybe and then pipe your results out to read them? something like

```
dir /s /b /o:gn
```

Gives you all sub files etc in a root directory you can use that to pipe your answer into something readable or stdout it direct into a variable in your code if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Zip Parent folder by using 7z commands or simply by Blueprism Zip Folder action and Use 7z Commands to extract recursive and relocate to single outputpath folder.

7zip tool is free of cost and usually every other organisation has these Tools.

Use recursive commands (X) of extraction and set the output path to a single location.
7z will do all the recursive fetching.

https://7ziphelp.com/7zip-command-line